# How to produce a bold \hbar symbol that looks similar to normal bold math font?

Tags: bold

I've been trying to write the reduced plank constant \hbar in bold font, but if I use the \bm command, it looks much thicker than normal bold math font. I've zoomed the resulting pdf in and I see the symbol as if two identical symbols were overlapped, as in the following screenshot:

[image: Zoomed in, bold \hbar symbol]

What can I do to produce this symbol in bold, so that the result looks like normal bold font?

**Edit:** here is my code. I'm not including the packages because I'm using too many in the preamble and I'm not much of a Latex expert so I'm not sure which ones are necessary and which ones are not.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,colbacktitle=red!80!black,title=Enunciado del problema 16,fonttitle=\bfseries,boxed title style={size=small,colframe=red!50!black} ] 
\vspace*{3mm}\textcolor{azure(colorwheel)}{\textbf{I'm writing a text with $\hbar$ and $\bm{hbar}$.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Some code? Or should we guess?

Comment: `\bm` only uses overprinting as a last resort, so if you are using a math font that has a bold version it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Sorry, I'll include it in a minute, but I just used \bm{\hbar}, that's why I thought it wasn't needed. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just included my code, do you think you could figure out why the \bm{} command is doing this? I have no idea. Maybe something is clashing here?

Comment: @egreg I just added the code.

Comment: @WildFeather No, that's not compilable and has a lot of irrelevant material. Please, make a *short* document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` showing the issue.

Comment: @egreg I think I solved my own problem while trying to provide a minimal working example for you, the issue was happening because of the amsfonts package. As soon as I removed it, writing \bm{\hbar} resulted in a perfect bold symbol exactly as I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @WildFeather no as you commented later I couldn't tell from the code posted as you had not posted any code that reproduced the problem. It's all about font setup and you have not posted any code relevant to that, that's why we always ask for complete test documents.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, I'm sorry that I didn't provide the example when I posted the question. I'll remember to always do it in the future, thank you!

Comment: can you either post an answer or delete so it's not left unanswered, thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course, done. I posted the answer instead of deleting, in case it might help someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been caused by the `amsfonts` package, that was forcing the `\bm` command to resort to overprinting the `\hbar` symbol to produce it in bold. Removing the `amsfonts` package from the preamble, regardless of the other packages included, solves the issue and produces a nice-looking, normal-thickness bold `\hbar` symbol when `\bm{\hbar}` is used.